# XCB xcb_window_t VS xcb_drawable_t

Tags: c, graphics, xorg, xcb

I'm trying to learn XCB through [this link](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/libxcb/tutorial/) and write a little "library" so I don't forget what to do each time. I'm at the point where I have a window open and I'm almost ready to start drawing things. However something has confused me, in some of the earlier examples they use xcb_window_t but in the new ones the make the "window" variable a xcb_drawable_t. I just went with it before but now I'm at the section "Simple window operations" and the functions seem to use xcb_window_t as inputs. Can these be used interchangeably, or do they need to be their own thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two kinds of drawables in X11: Windows and pixmaps.
Put differently: A window is a drawable and a pixmap is a drawable. Nothing else is a drawable.

Every function that accepts a `xcb_drawable_t` can be called with either a window or a pixmap. Functions that want a window only accept `xcb_window_t`.